# how to use papertrail (send logs) in nest js?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, papertrail-app

is there any way to use **papertrail** in nestjs application ? I am added loggers like this
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger

Now I want to send this logs to **papertrail**.. is there any way to send ?

I got the example of nodejs . but I didn't find any example of nestjs

Comment: can you edit your question to show us the example that you have on nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

You could send it to SQL or NoSQL. Eventually, you want to store a log record.

Or you could save it on your local server by creating your own log file.

Comment: I believe OP is asking about [papertrail the logregator](https://www.papertrail.com/), not a "papertrail" of their logs.